# MariaDB 10.3 Replication doesn't work -> Exec_Master_Log_Pos does not change

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, replication

I configured a replication cluster with MariaDB 10.3. I can connect from my slave to my master and all write statements from my master is automatically copied to my relay-bin files on my slaves. But then the queries in my relay bin file are not executed on my databases. Furthermore the Exec_Master_Log_Pos does not change meanwhile the Read_Master_Log_Pos does.

I cannot stop the slave because if i do the process hangs and i have to kill it. the Seconds Behind Master grows...

here are my show slave status on my slave server:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show slave status \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                   Master_Host: mymaster.test.net
                   Master_User: repadmin
                   Master_Port: 3306
                 Connect_Retry: 60
               Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000001
           Read_Master_Log_Pos: 498
                Relay_Log_File: slave-relay-bin.000002
                 Relay_Log_Pos: 555
         Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000001
              Slave_IO_Running: Yes
             Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
               Replicate_Do_DB:
           Replicate_Ignore_DB:
            Replicate_Do_Table:
        Replicate_Ignore_Table:
       Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
   Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                    Last_Errno: 0
                    Last_Error:
                  Skip_Counter: 0
           Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 328
               Relay_Log_Space: 1038
               Until_Condition: None
                Until_Log_File:
                 Until_Log_Pos: 0
            Master_SSL_Allowed: No
            Master_SSL_CA_File:
            Master_SSL_CA_Path:
               Master_SSL_Cert:
             Master_SSL_Cipher:
                Master_SSL_Key:
         Seconds_Behind_Master: 52
 Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                 Last_IO_Errno: 0
                 Last_IO_Error:
                Last_SQL_Errno: 0
                Last_SQL_Error:
   Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
              Master_Server_Id: 1
                Master_SSL_Crl:
            Master_SSL_Crlpath:
                    Using_Gtid: No
                   Gtid_IO_Pos:
       Replicate_Do_Domain_Ids:
   Replicate_Ignore_Domain_Ids:
                 Parallel_Mode: conservative
                     SQL_Delay: 0
           SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
       Slave_SQL_Running_State: Update
              Slave_DDL_Groups: 0
Slave_Non_Transactional_Groups: 0
    Slave_Transactional_Groups: 1
1 row in set (0.000 sec)



show processlist:
10 | system user |  | NULL   | Slave_IO  | 1766 | Waiting for master to send event | NULL                         |    0.000 |
| 11 | system user | | testdb | Slave_SQL |  183 | Update                           | insert into test values (10) |    0.000 |
```

It seems that the update process always hangs. 
As i said before the queries are copied to my slaves relays-logs but not executed on my database.

Comment: If you are using 10.3.17 (exactly this version), and have `innodb_thread_concurrency` in your configuration, you are most likely affected by the bug [MDEV-20247](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-20247). Despite the name, it is not limited to `Preparing` phase in IO thread.

Comment: Yes, i have changed the value from innodb_thread_concurrency to zero and now it works. Thanks!